# React Native Keyboard covers TextInput KeyboardAvoidingView on Android

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard, expo

I want to create a TextInput for a chat app. On Ios all works fine but on Android the TextInput is covered if the Keyboard is opened:[image]

It should look the same than on Ios:
[image]

My Code looks  like this:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView enabled behavior={Platform.OS == 'ios' ? 'padding' : null} keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS == 'ios' ? null : 90} style={{felx: 1, width: "100%", flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center", marginVertical: 5, justifyContent: "center" }}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            ...
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TextInput style={{
            height: 47,
            width: "80%",
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            paddingHorizontal: 10,
            borderRadius: 14,
            color: "grey",
            fontSize: 17,
          }}
          editable={this.state.inputdisabled}
          placeholder={"Nachricht..."}
          value={nachricht}
          blur={true}
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          multiline
          clearButtonMode='always'
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({nachricht: text})}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity>
            ..
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After executing the expo app to the bare workflow all looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine, you can wrap the content inside the KeyboardAvoidingView body in a view and make move your styling inside the view